# Vue router being loaded before Vuex and the app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

When the vue app is being created, it will dispatch an action from the store that hits the backend endpoint to fetch the user data and update the user state.

I wanted to use navigation guards (either beforeEnter inside the relevant route or beforeRouteEnter inside the component) so it will check if the user data has the right permissions to route to the component. However, when I try to access either store.state or store.getters, it returns the empty data because the router is loaded before the action in the store is completed yet.

I tried different solutions I found online but not much luck yet..The following is a snippet of the code.

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    this.setupAxios()
    this.fetchInitial()
  },
  methods: {
    setupAxios(){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = window.csrfToken
    },
    fetchInitial(){
      this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_USER_PROFILE')
    },
  }
}
```

```
const actions = {
  ['FETCH_USER_PROFILE']: ({commit, dispatch}) => {
    return axios.get(reverseJS['api2:users-list']())
      .then(resp => {
        commit('FETCH_USER_PROFILE', resp.data)
        return resp.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        commit('USERS_ERROR', error)
        throw error
      })
  },
}
```

Comment: have you tried initializing your store before your initializing your app? e.g `store.dispatch().then(() => new Vue())`

Comment: I think @doesnotmatter had the right idea here. The place to do this should be your main.js/main.ts do your async call and after its done initialize your app.